# Is it possible to build a 1080p OSD webcam shield?

Tags: shields

What do I need to build a shield capable of receiving 1080p video from USB camera, timestamp each frame and send the frame to memory card?

Comment: It would require so much hardware in terms of memory, speed and specialized peripherals, that it renders adding an Arduino to the mix pointless.

Comment: You would be better off with a Raspberry Pi connected to the USB port via serial and to send when to start/stop. The YUN might be able to handle it, but you'll have to write your own device drivers. Also, the TRE (not available yet) might work.

Answer (score 5):

None of the ATmega based boards have the hardware (in terms of acting as a USB host) or power (in terms of handling probably compressed 1080p video).

Potentially one of the ARM boards could do this. The Arduino Due can act as a host, but it sounds fairly experimental, and none of them will have drivers to connect to the camera.

If a shield was developed to do this, it would have so much more power than the Arduino that the Arduino would probably better be viewed as a slave to the other device.

Comment: The Arduino Due has a port that can act as a USB host. You'd still have driver issues, though.

Comment: Raspberry Pi...